# Any way to rename a database of a published app?

Tags: android, database

Is there anyway to rename a database of a published android app? I am working something out to just change the database name and onCreate of that database, check for the old database and copy the contents out, but wondering if thats my only recourse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try renaming the file before opening it the first time. It is located in:

```
getApplication().getDatabasePath("databasename");
```

Replace "databasename" with the one you are using.

And when you open it for the first time afterwards, use the new name you have selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following java commands

```
File f = new File(PATH + DB_NAME);
f.renameTo(new File(PATH + NEWName));
```

Where `PATH` is the path on the device

Answer (score 0):

```
File database=getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("oldDatabase.db");
if (database.exists()) {
    File newPath = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("newDatabase.db");
    database.renameTo(newPath);
}
```